How can I implement a multi-condition (AND condition) check when working with Amplify @auth rules?
How can I implement a multi-condition (AND condition) check when working with Amplify @auth rules? Not having much luck finding documentation on AND multi-condition auth design.
I'm building up a Graphql schema in Amplify deployed using amplify add api and trying to figure out how to create a nested @auth condition check or a multi-condition check such as a AND condition. The goal is to have two checks take place before authorization is granted such as having to be apart of an Organization and an Admin.
In theory the requester for the below type would need to have a value of "admin" for the custom:OrganizationRole Cognito custom attribute and their custom:Organization value from Cognito should match the ownership.organization value. If any of the two are false they should not have access.
type Organization @model @auth(rules: [{
    allow: groups
    groupClaim: "custom:Organization"
    ownerField: "ownership.organization"
    provider: userPools
    operations: [read, update]
}, {
    allow: groups
    groupClaim: "custom:OrganizationRole"
    groupsField: "admin"
    provider: userPools
    operations: [read, update]
}]){
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    address_primary: Address
    address_secondary: Address
    common_properties: CommonProperties!
    ownership: Ownership!
}

Tried to add it as an and:{AuthRule} however got the below error
Field "and" is not defined by type "AuthRule".

GraphQL request:3:130
3 | }type Organization @model @auth(rules: [{allow: owner, identityClaim: "sub", own
  | erField: "ownership.owner", provider: userPools, and: {allow: groups, groupClaim
  |                                                  ^
  | : "custom:OrganizationRole", groupsField: "admin", provider: userPools, operatio


